# How can I access database variables in my custom module

Tags: database

I have used PDO DB connection in my custom module. I wanted to know how can I access the Database variables from (settings file) in my custom module. Or is there any way to make PDO DB connection globally so that it can be used every where it needed in custom module.

My code is below:

```
function my_module_init() {

    $path_val=request_path();

    $exploded_val=explode("/",$path_val);

    $value1=$exploded_val[4];

    if($value1=='test')   
    { 

    $servername ="host";
    $username = "test1";
    $password = "test2";
    $dbname = "test3";        

    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);        
    $query = $conn->exec("TRUNCATE TABLE table_name");

    $sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (test_id)
    VALUES ('$test_id')";
    $conn->exec($sql);         
    $conn = null;        

    }
    }
```

Comment: I you're just writing custom PHP code you should do it whichever way you're comfortable doing it. If you start using the Drupal API at any point please ask a specific question about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to access the connection variables directly. Drupal 7 comes with a full database API that handles the connection for you, and can be used from anywhere in your module. Some common functions in the API are [db_query()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21database.inc/function/db_query/8.2.x), [db_select()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21database.inc/function/db_select/8.2.x), [db_insert()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21database.inc/function/db_insert/8.2.x), [db_update](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21database.inc/function/db_delete/8.2.x), [db_delete()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21database.inc/function/db_delete/8.2.x) and [db_merge()](http://drupaltonight.com/drupal-articles/using-dbmerge-query-insert-or-update)

You can read all about the Database API here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/database-api/database-api-overview

Comment: `db_merge` is my favorite